# Как пропускать символ перехода на новую строку при чтении из файла?

Tags: c++, строки, файлы

После считывания из файла, у меня считывается строка с символом перехода на новую строку, в итоге при попытке узнать длину строки выводит длину на 1 символ больше чем нужно. Как сделать так что бы символ перехода на новую строку не считывался?

```
int main() {
int i = 0;
while(fgets(str[i], 100, ptr) != NULL) {
    arr[i] = strlen(str[i])-1;
    cout << arr[i]<< endl;
    i++;
}
_getch();
```

}

Comment: читайте  каждую строку отдельно и аккумилируйте  длины строк в исходный обьект i.     Или читайте посимвольно и при достижении  символа перехода строки, игнорируйте очередной символ, вызовом   istream::ignore()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он все равно обязан быть считан :) - иначе вы следующим чтением получите пустую строку, нет? :)

Словом, есть стандартная библиотека, и стандарт работы функций. И в рамках этого стандарта приходится работать. Если использовать `FILE` в С++ - то я бы на вашем месте просто делал что-то типа

```
int len = strlen(str[i]);
if (str[len-1]=='\n') str[--len] = 0; // Проверка нужна - строка может быть слишком длинной
arr[i] = len;
```

Comment: Перевод каретки бывает часто `\r\n` тогда прийдётся аналогично убрать `\r`

Comment: @nick_n_a Не придется - если файл открыт в текстовом режиме (а вряд ли кто будет читать текст в бинарном режиме) - то это делается системой автоматически.